# Save Html source from browser with JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a simple Html list application on my local computer with save functionality locally, new list items added to the list and saved. I was searching online but I have found only complicated solutions that required an input object to save. I would like to ask if the following code can work with some modification.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
Content...
        <button onclick="save()">Save</button>
</body>
<script src="setup.js"></script>
</html>
```

setup.js

```
async function save(content){
    let fileData = new File([""], "index.html");
    let stream = fileData.createWritable();
    let text = "text";
    await stream.write(text);
    await stream.close();
```

Comment: `new File([""], "index.html");` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Browser cannot write and read from the file system without explicit permission. It would be a great security risk otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a very recent Chromium browser, you can use window.showSaveFilePicker. ([https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker])
From the docs:

```
function getNewFileHandle() { 
  const opts = {
    types: [{
      description: 'Text file',
      accept: {'text/plain': ['.txt']},
    }],
  };
  return window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);
}
async function writeFile(fileHandle, contents) {
// Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
  const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
  // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
  await writable.write(contents);
  // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
  await writable.close();
}
```